# count records from a single table with different status code

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I wanna write a sql in which I want to count records from a single table with different status code.
I wrote a query like this

```
select 
(    
    (
        select count(*) as "Entry"
        from cn_grc_hdr hdr
        where hdr.unit_code = '03' and 
            hdr.crt_dt > '12-may-2013' and 
            hdr.status = 'E'
    ),
    (
        select count(*) as "Authorised" 
        from cn_grc_hdr hdr
        where hdr.unit_code = '03' and 
            hdr.crt_dt > '12-may-2013' and 
            hdr.status = 'A'   
    )
)
from dual
```

When I execute this query it shows an error (in oracle sql developer)

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" Cause:    Action: Error at Line: 5 Column: 5

might be my formatting is wrong. Can someone help me to write query like this?

Comment: So I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the problem is that you have the two sub queries wrapped in parenthesis. Get rid of those outer parenthesis.

Comment: I removed outer parenthesis and wrote query below and



select 
        (select count(*)
        from cn_grc_hdr hdr
        where hdr.unit_code = '03' and 
            hdr.crt_dt > '12-may-2013' and 
            hdr.status = 'E') "Entry"
    ,
    
        (select count(*)
        from cn_grc_hdr hdr
        where hdr.unit_code = '03' and 
            hdr.crt_dt > '12-may-2013' and 
            hdr.status = 'A' ) "Authorised" 
from dual






Yes @neoistheone it is working.

Comment: Okay, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have re-written the query

```
select DECODE(status, 'E', 'Entry', 'A', 'Authorised') as Status , count(*) 
FROM table
where unit_code = '03' 
and crd_dt > to_date('12-May-2013', 'dd-MON-yyyy') 
and status in ('A', 'E')
GROUP BY status;
```

Comment: After Executing it------------->


ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 1

Comment: I think you have to group by status for this to work.

Comment: Thanks dcp for notifying my mistake. Overlooked the sql. Edited.